# Append a plot to the NULL elements of a list in R

Tags: r

My goal is to lengthen, re-order, and fill a list of plots with 'empty' plots
if any list elements are missing.

So far my attempt has been able to lengthen and re-order a partial list, yet I am struggling
to assign the empty plots. Here is the partial list and the desired output, as well as the code of my attempt.

How may I append an 'emptyPlot` to each NULL element of 'l3' ? Or is there a different way to do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
somePlot <- ggplot() + ggtitle("Some plot.")+ theme_bw() 
emptyPlot <- ggplot() + ggtitle("Nothing to see here.") + theme_void() 
  
# input list
partial_list <- list(fourth = somePlot, first = somePlot)

# desired output
desired <- list(first = somePlot, second = somePlot, third = emptyPlot, fourth = somePlot)

# a reference vector for what the list should contain that also specifies the desired order
reference <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")

# convert missing elements to NA 
reference[!reference %in% names(partial_list)] <- NA

# lengthen list with NAs
l2 <- c(partial_list, rep(NA, sum(is.na(reference))))

# reorder to follow the reference
l3 <- l2[reference]

# this approach did not give the desired output.
appendEmptyPlot <- function(x) {x[is.null(x)] <- emptyPlot; x}

l4 <- lapply(l3, appendEmptyPlot)
l4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a loop like this:

```r
for (r in reference) {
   if (!r %in% names(partial_list))
   partial_list[[r]] <- emptyPlot
 }

l4 <- partial_list[reference]
```